# Can I block log messages from specific devices or drivers?

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, syslog, dmesg

I'm getting "NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier()" messages in syslog and dmesg at a rate of 4-6 per minute; I think it's from the Nvidia graphics driver.

The system behaves normally, but the messages clutter up the logs so I can't find any real issues. (At the moment dmesg is 4,000 lines and 3,925 of those lines are the same message.)

Is it possible to suppress or redirect these messages?

Example log snippet:

```
Mar 13 20:38:04 desktop kernel: [175481.413559] NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier(), invalid context!
Mar 13 20:38:04 desktop kernel: [175481.430904] NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier(), invalid context!
Mar 13 20:38:45 desktop kernel: [175522.223337] NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier(), invalid context!
Mar 13 20:38:45 desktop kernel: [175522.239655] NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier(), invalid context!
Mar 13 20:38:47 desktop kernel: [175523.556706] NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier(), invalid context!
Mar 13 20:38:47 desktop kernel: [175523.572015] NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier(), invalid context!
```

Comment: I thought this sounded familiar, it did: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/656279. I'm pretty sure a driver or kernel upgrade fixed it for my lappy but forget which (I stopped it at the time I read that bug report).

Comment: @msw Thanks, a driver update did the trick. Still interested in the question, as this is not the first time (and probably not the last) I have had "log spamming", and I'd like to know a general solution.

Comment: which is why I commented rather than answered (and upvoted your self-answer)

Answer (score 5):

I have half an answer: I don't know how to block specific drivers, but rsyslog has a mechanism for [filtering log messages on content](http://www.rsyslog.com/writing-specific-messages-to-a-file-and-discarding-them/):

Edit the rsyslog configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

Add a text filter at the top of the file, and redirect the messages matching the filter to a separate log:

```
:msg, contains, "NVRM: os_raise_smp_barrier" -/var/log/junk.log
& ~
```

Save the file and restart rsyslog:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Check that the restart worked:

```
$ tail /var/log/syslog
...
Mar 14 10:38:35 desktop kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Mar 14 10:38:35 desktop kernel: imklog 4.2.0, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Mar 14 10:38:35 desktop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.2.0" x-pid="18494" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Mar 14 10:38:35 desktop rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Mar 14 10:38:35 desktop rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
```

And `/var/log` should now contain a new log file `junk.log` containing the filtered messages.

So far so good, the only drawback is that it doesn't work for `dmesg`.